# Create new columns conditionally in reactable from R

Tags: r, reactable

I am trying to make a `reactable` with the following (I succeeded making the first but not 2 and 3):

1. If a row in any column is above `5` **or** below `0.1`, color that cell `red`.
2. Create a new column that counts the number of red cells for every row. For instance, since the first row has two red cells, the value is 2.
3. Create another column that is either `1` or `0`: `1` if all four columns in a certain row are all `white` and `0` otherwise. For instance, since the 7th row does not have any red cells, the value will be 1.
   [image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

reactable(
iris,
columns = set_names(x = colnames(iris)) %>% 
    map(~ {
    colDef(
        style = function(value) {
        ds_color <- ifelse(value > 5 | value <= 0.2, "red", "white")
        list(background = ds_color)
        }
    )
    })
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `if_all/if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
   mutate(color_ind = case_when(if_any(where(is.numeric), ~ 
     .x > 5|.x < 1)~ "red",TRUE ~  "white"),
   cnt_col = rowSums(across(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width, 
       ~ .x > 5|.x < 1), na.rm = TRUE),
    binary_white = +(!cnt_col))
```